# How to check if a file exists under include path?

Tags: php, yii

You get the current include path in PHP by using `get_include_path()`

I am wondering what is the lightweight way to check if the file can be included without issuing a PHP error. I am using Yii framework and I want to an import without issuing PHP error, but I fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before PHP 5.3.2 you can split the path and check each path in a loop:

```
$find = 'file.php'; //The file to find
$paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
$found = false;
foreach($paths as $p) {
  $fullname = $p.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$find;
  if(is_file($fullname)) {
    $found = $fullname;
    break;
  }
}
//$found now contains the file to be included, or false if not found
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks, I looked it up right after I posted this. It wasn't too easy to find in the manual.

Comment: For what environment is `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` ever different from "/"? (Hint: For this purpose, "/" works just fine under Windows.)

Answer (score 34):

As of PHP 5.3.2, you can use

- [`stream_resolve_include_path` — Resolve filename against the include path](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-resolve-include-path.php)

which will

> Returns a string containing the resolved absolute filename, or FALSE on failure.

#### Example from Manual:

```
 var_dump(stream_resolve_include_path("test.php"));
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
 string(22) "/var/www/html/test.php"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me trying to find a directory that actually exists in include_path. And neither does real_path(). No error message.

Comment: @DavidSpector , what are you trying to do exactly? This solution is for checking "if a file exists under include path", not for finding a directory.

Comment: Sorry, "include_path" seemed to mean directory, since an include path contains paths of directories only, not of files. Now that I look at the documentation for stream_resolve_include_path, I see it refers to testing a file. Never mind.