# Check whether FirePHP is installed in PHP code

Tags: php, pear, libraries, firephp

Is there any way to determine whether FirePHP is installed on the server (via PEAR)? I'd like to make  possible logging in FirePHP but also not to crash the code for everyone without that tool.

The example, how I imagine it should work:

```
$message = "hello";
function log($message) {
    if (library_exists('FirePHPCore/fb.php')) {
        require_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');
        ob_start();
        \FB::log($message);
    } else {
        SomeBoringLogger::log($message);
    }
}
```

I haven't found anything like my **library_exists** method. Is there anything like that in PHP?

Comment: **Any** php library shouldn't be installed in a system shared directories. You can just copy the directory with your project and include it from *any* directory you have write access to.

Comment: `is_file('FirePHPCore/fb.php')`?

Comment: @Rocket: `is_file` doesn't respect include paths

Comment: Search the include path. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041250/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-under-include-path

Comment: Also - it's not a good idea either. If you don't check the firephp version - it's a chance to start using obsolete and vulnerable version of it. So if you really need it - I would recommend just having a copy of it in your distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@include_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php'); // Ignore any errors here, as we check for existance
if (class_exists('FirePHP')) { // Do something after this
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

[FirePHP uses `FirePHP` as its class name](https://github.com/cadorn/firephp-libs/blob/master/packages/core/lib/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php), so if it is available, that class should be defined

---

For PHP 5.3.2 or later, use zerkms's suggestion:

```
(!stream_resolve_include_path('FirePHPCore/fb.php')===FALSE)
```

Comment: Add an "include_once" before that.

Comment: And what would happen if no such file found?

Comment: @zerkms, With the `@` out front, the PHP warning will be ignored.  Unfortunately since it is not an exception, it can't be caught with `try`/`catch`.  Since this is `include` and not `require`, the script won't fail.

Comment: @Brad: yep, you added `@` after my comment. PS: there are solutions without terrible `@` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6041325/251311

Comment: @zerkms, Good to know!  That is a much better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `include_once`, so it doesn't kill the request. As @Brad suggests, use `class_exists` afterwards.

```
$message = "hello";

safe_include_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');
if (class_exists('FB')) {
   function log($message) { 
      //using FirePHP
   }
} else {
   function log($message) {
      SomeBoringLogger::log($message);
   }
}

function safe_include_once($path) {
  if ($path = stream_resolve_include_path($path)) {
    include_once($path);
  }
}
```

[Edit] Using `stream_resolve_include_path` in `safe_include_path`.

[Edit2] Faster runtime logging.

Comment: And there will be a warning if the file wasn't found

Answer (score 0):

`file_exists()` can be used for your case.